# How can I display limited row on rdlc report?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 10 rows in database.in my database billid,srno,product are column respectivly.im my database 252 billid are in 10 rows,but srno 1 are in four times in row and srno 2 are six times on that billid.i want to display srno 1 on 1st page and srno 2 on second page of rdlc report.how can i do this?
I tried this but all rows are display on one page.

Comment: I would hate to see how the question looked before Soner edited it. Can you clarify a litte? Unless maybe I'm just an idiot and this makes perfect sense.

Comment: how can i display limited row with id on rdlc report